# macOS High Sierra Messages, how can I find a closed conversation?

Tags: macos, messages

I have some conversations in Messages.app that I have previously closed.  I would like to find one of them again.  These were not deleted, merely closed.  How can I get them back once again?

Comment: Would [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/save-or-delete-conversations-icht1035/11.0/mac/10.13) answer your question? See the note after the "Close a Conversation" bullet.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried composing a message, and the old conversation does not appear.  Maybe it would if I actually sent a message to the person, but I most definitely do not want to do that (this is not someone I want to have contact with again).